# Zebra ZD410 print from https

Tags: zebra-printers, network-printers

I'm trying to get my Zebra ZD410 to print labels from a website. That website is not mine. It runs on https. My printer does work, is connected to my computer, I can send ZPL instructions. The printer is actually connected to my Wi-Fi and has a static IP address of "192.168.2.80".

When browsing to "http://192.168.2.80" the print server page shows up.

The website in question supports, for now, only the Zebra 410 (and most probably other version, just not tested). Their instructions are to click on a link to accept the SSL certificate. Upon clicking on that link, a new page is opened and tries to load https://192.168.2.80, which is refused with "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

I have tried and successfully sent "!U1 setvar "ip.https.enable" "on" and restarted the printer, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. You're talking about printing from https, which is doable, but what you're trying to do is to open the printer web page using the https protocol, which is unsupported as the web page can only be opened using http. Can you clarify the printing process?

Comment: The process is the website in question sends, over https, on the printer's address, zpl commands on the api endpoint "/pstprnt". Upon testing using insomnia, it works when sending the same request with https, but not https that ends as connection refused. When sending the command "! U1 getvar "file.cert.expiration"" I can see that https has no file, might that be the issue, a missing certificate? EDIT. Clicking on that link is meant, according to the website in question, to "accept the ssl certificate" and must be done once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- By default, the printer comes with http enabled
- Always add a carriage return at the end of your commands in the communication tool
- One can enable https by sending `! U1 setvar "ip.https.enable" "on"`
- The printer comes with no self-signed default certificate for SSL, that's a shame
- Anybody can generate self-signed certificates, by opening a terminal and make sure you have `openssl` installed then type :

  - `openssl genrsa 2048 > HTTPS_KEY.NRD`
  - `openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha256 -days 365 -key HTTPS_KEY.NRD > HTTPS_CERT.NRD`

    - **The certificate file must be named HTTPS_CERT.NRD**
    - **The private key file must be named HTTPS_KEY.NRD**
- Get both files EXACT byte sizes
- Files must be manually uploaded in binary mode on the printer on E: (any other method will fail on ZD410, be it driver upload, serial upload, ftp upload, or setup utility upload, because the default destination is not E: but R: and is not RW)

  - Open Zebra setup utility
  - Open communication tools
  - Enter following commands

```
~DYE:HTTPS_CERT.nrd,B,NRD,REPLACE WITH FILE BYTE SIZE,,-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
REPLACE WITH YOUR CERTIFICATE CONTENT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
~DYE:HTTPS_KEY.nrd,B,NRD,REPLACE WITH FILE BYTE SIZE,,-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- 
REPLACE WITH YOUR KEY CNTENT
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
^XA
^JUS
^XZ
! U1 setvar "ip.https.enable" "on"
! U1 do "device.reset" ""
```

Upon restart, one can check if the https webserver was enabled with a command:

- `! U1 getvar "file.cert"`

  - The printer will answer with all the loaded certificates.
  - Check the line with HTTPS service. It should have a file and a validity

You can then navigate, on your browser to your printer's ip using https and also send https API triggers.

If you wish to then turn off http, you can disable it by sending this command:

`! U1 setvar "ip.http.enable" "off"`

Comment: Thank you for the hint about the file names. However, I could not get the commands above to work, I eventually used the 'Store file to printer' via 'Printer Settings' (be sure to set destination as 'Internal Flash'), and it worked on ZT230.

Comment: I'm able to write these files to E: using my own tool (just a simple socket client).  I don't get much of a response from the printer, but the files show up in the directory listing on http://<ip>.

For the exact file sizes, I am using the value I see on disk before I copy out, but maybe it needs to be the actual payload between the -----BEGIN...----- and -----END...-----?

Comment: I tried everything but it didn't seem to work.
By the way you have a type in: 
~DYE:HTTPS_CERT.nrd,B,NRD,
the file name should not have the extentiion
~DYE:HTTPS_CERT,B,NRD, Instead.

Comment: The issue was, I was using openssl from linux which uses different algorithms that are probably not supported by the printer. Now I use a VM with openssl binary found in the [demo documentation](https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/000022515?language=en_US#:~:text=Execute%20ZEBRA-PRINTSECURE_DEMO_SCRIPT.bat%20from%20the%20below%20folder%20path%3A%20C%3AZebraprintsecure-demo,then%20be%20sent%20and%20stored%20on%20the%20printer)
 and [here](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/techdocs/linkos-demos/printsecure/zebra-printsecure-demo.exe) the link for the installer